# Multiple date formats for angular ui bootstrap datepicker

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have the following HTML below in my app.

```
<p class="input-group">
    <input ng-model="myDate" datepicker-popup="MM/dd/yyyy" 
           is-open="isopen" />
    <span style="cursor:pointer" ng-click="opendate($event)" class="input-group-addon input-sm"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
</p>
```

I would like to have the ngModel populated when the user enters the date in the format `4.3.2015` or `4.3.15` , but currently i am getting ngModel as undefined.
How can i tell the datepicker to accept other date formats as well?

Please check this plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/t1f9AkHeKzvyPTQNzvxf?p=preview, This works in Chrome but not in IE . You can type 4.4.15 in chrome and it works, the same does not work in IE

Comment: The example on the [docs](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker) shows how to use multiple formats along with a plnkr you can edit. Have you tried format `M.d.yyyy` or `d.M.yyyy`?

Comment: Is the date `4.3.15` supposed to be "April 3, 2015" or "4 March 2015" or "2004 March 15" or ...?

Comment: April 3rd.The moment i remove the line datepicker-popup="MM/dd/yyyy"  , popup is not opening.

Comment: `datepicker-popup` is the name of the datepicker directive so without that it won't try to look for `ng-model`. Share your code with us so others can _duplicate the problem_ to better understand what you're trying to do and where you're going wrong.

Comment: Please check this plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/t1f9AkHeKzvyPTQNzvxf?p=preview, This works in Chrome but not in IE . You can type 4.4.15 in chrome and it works, the same does not work in IE

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to allow the user to decide how they enter their date format?

As far as I know, the date format needs to be defined beforehand and cannot be "detected" as the user fills it in. But, you could create an array with accepted date formats in your controller:

```
// Accepted date formats.
$scope.formats = ['MM/dd/yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate'];

// Default date format.
$scope.format = $scope.formats[0];
```

Change the datepicker-popup attribute to `datepicker-popup="{{format}}"` in your HTML input field.

The user could have a dropdown (HTML select) menu in the view where they can select their preferred date format, which will change the value of `$scope.format`. The datepicker will change accordingly.

Comment: The moment i remove the line datepicker-popup="MM/dd/yyyy" , popup is not opening. But if that line is not there then ngModel is not set to undefined.I am getting values in ngModel. is that how its suppose to work ?

Comment: Please check this plunkr plnkr.co/edit/t1f9AkHeKzvyPTQNzvxf?p=preview, This works in Chrome but not in IE . You can type 4.4.15 in chrome and it works, the same does not work in IE .

Comment: Date format works only for defaulted format .e.g. if you enter manually from accepted date format then it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

I have used the **alt-input-formats** on the DateParser to provide alternate formats

```
alt-input-formats (Default: []) - A list of alternate formats acceptable for manual entry.
```